# Objective c : problem with directory file

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, plist

I have this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"]; 


if([array writeToFile:path atomically: YES]){
    NSLog(@"write succesful");}
else {
    NSLog(@"write failed");
}
```

I create in folder Resources a file "File.plist" and I want store an NSMutableArray inside it. When I call this method the message in console is "write succesful" but if I change the path in

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileAbstract.plist"];
```

the message is ever "write succesful? Why? I changed name in path.

Comment: looks like you created a second file, have you had a look in the directory?

Comment: How can I look in the directory?

Comment: You can find the app in the simulator folder it's normally found at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications`.

Comment: use the method `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` of the NSFileManager class then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you are writing in document directory, which has no relation with the resource folder in the project. You cannot change files in resource folders by running the app. In first run you have written file `File.plist` and in 2nd run you have written file `FileAbstract.plist`, both in document directory. They have no relation with the `File.plist` in resource folder.

EDIT: To read the content of the file in an array:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: ah ok I understand, and Can I see File.plist?

Comment: In simulator you can check files easily. On device, I have heard that it is possible via sync/backup app data with iTunes, but never tried myself. So can't confirm that. And you can create a NSArray with method arrayWithContentsOfFile:path and check the content of the array.